# HTML Error Using wp_get_attachment_image

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This code :

```
$src = wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), 'medium' );
$url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_the_ID(), 'full' );

printf( '<p><a href="%s"><img src="%s"></a></p>', $url, $src );
```

Produces this :

[image]

Which is this HTML

```
<a href="http://www.dev.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/p.png"><img src="<img width=" 300"="" class="attachment-medium size-medium" alt="" srcset="http://www.dev.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/p-300x169.png 300w, http://www.dev.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/p-768x432.png 768w, http://www.dev.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/p-1024x576.png 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" height="169">"&gt;</a>
```

Why is this?

I cannot see any problem with this code :

```
printf( '<p><a href="%s"><img src="%s"></a></p>', $url, $src );
```

Answer (score 3):

`wp_get_attachment_image` return full image tag. So You don't need to add `<img src` tag. Change your code

```
printf( '<p><a href="%s"><img src="%s"></a></p>', $url, $src );
```

to

```
printf( '<p><a href="%s">"%s"</a></p>', $url, $src );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i changed it to. Thanks for the point in the right direction B.Desai

```
 printf( '<p><a href="%s">%s</a></p>', $url, $src );
```

[wp_get_attachment_image](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) returns (string) HTML img element or empty string on failure.